# Can I initialize a static member from within another function?

Tags: c++, static, scope, initialization, member

There is a static member in a `struct`, because it is needed in the destructor.

```
struct Form
{
    // ...
    ~Form()
    {
        // access World here
    }
    static btDynamicsWorld *World;
};
```

Is there a way to initialize this static member from within another function?

```
void ModulePhysics::Init()
{
    // ...
    btDynamicsWorld *Form::World = /* ... */;
}
```

My current code results in those two compiler errors.

> Error 1 error C2655: 'Form::World' : definition or redeclaration illegal in current scope
>
> Error 2 error C2086: 'btDynamicsWorld *Form::World' : redefinition

Comment: Are you sure, a static member is what you want? It will be the same for every instance of the class!

Comment: @Sebastian The `struct` represents rigid bodies in a physics simulation. The `World` is represents the space for physics interaction between many bodies, only one instance exists. Bodies must be removed from the world on destruction, otherwise the simulation would crash. If there is a better way to handle this, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Comment: You are aware that declaring a variable static within a struct does not reserve any RAM for it and that you need a second declaration of its RAM elsewhere right?

Comment: @danijar: If this "World" is not directly connected to the "Form" class, it may be a better design to have it as a simple global variable (static, or in a namespace, or a Singleton)

Comment: Seems like it might be better to have a World object that has lots of body objects.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I agree, but this is how the Bullet Physics library designed it.

Comment: @Sebastian It would be the first global variable in my whole application. But that's not an argument against. Why would you use a global variable instead?

Comment: @danjar: A static member of a class is a global variable, too, regarding it's lifetime. Just it's scope is different. So if it's not a part of the Form class, conceptually, you win nothing by putting it in there.

Comment: Are you sure, there will be one world, ever? (You might want to simulate two worlds in parallel...). Otherwise, you should make the world a normal member of the Form class, create the world (as a normal variable in your simulation main function) and pass a pointer to the world to the constructor of the Form class. Disadvantage: Form instances consume more memory.

Comment: Are you sure you must remove the Form from the World in the destructor? Can't you call the destructor from the function which removes the Form from the World?

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks a lot for your thoughts, I appreciate that! Both ideas you suggested won't work since the world instance in only known in one source file while forms must be created and destructed from within many source files.

Comment: Singleton pattern yet again.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I think it would be possible. What are the advantages? I actually tried implementing it and failed. At the moment I am pretty happy with the easy setup for the static member variable.

Comment: Singleton: Just move the static variable from the Form class into the World class. Make it private and encapsulate all accesses in (static) methods of the World class.

Comment: @Sebastian I cannot modify the type of `World` which is `btDynamicsWorld`. I would need a wrapper. What are the advantages?

Comment: There's no technical advantage. Just "better design" in the sense of "where would I look for the World instance... somewhere in the World class!). When you can't modify the World class, it's probably better to use a namespace than a wrapper for the World class. For example, in the namespace "Simulation". Which makes even more sense, because the WOrld instance is part of the Simulation, not of the World class, conceptually. In my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. But you can initialize it to NULL, and in the function, if it is NULL, do the real initialization.

Edit: Provide an example:

```
void ModulePhysics::Init()
{
    // ...
    if(Form::World == NULL)
    {
        // The real initialization
    }
}
```

Somewhere, on file scope (in the C file, not in the header!):

```
btDynamicsWorld* Form::World = NULL;
```

Comment: That would be great, could you please provide a short code example?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It compiles now. Would I need to initialize the static member in every source file including the struct?

Comment: No. You must define it in one file, you may not define it in more than one file (one definition rule, ODR)

Comment: Great to hear! So the value is shared between all source files?

Comment: Yes. It's shared between all source files. Unlike file scope static variables.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.

> The declaration of a static data member in the member list of a class is not a definition. You must define the static member outside of the class declaration, **in namespace scope**.

[Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr038.htm) you can get a more detailed description of how and where you can initialize static class variables.

Answer (score 0):

in the init() method remove the type in front of the static variable.

it should solve your issue, I hope.

Comment: I tried that before but it throws a `unresolved external symbol` linker error.

Answer (score 0):

1) All static class members (except integral members initialized immediately in the class definition) should also be defined outside (preferrably in a .cpp file, so that the definition is processed only once by compiler). For example:

```
// form.h
struct Form
{
    static btDynamicsWorld *World;
};


// form.cpp

// You can initialize World here as well if you want to,
// but you don't have to, as long as it's not const.
// However, it is generally a good idea to initialize
// pointers to NULL (or nullptr in C++11).
btDynamicsWorld *Form::World;
```

This can only be done at global scope. If you don't do this, you will get linker errors (undefined symbol) if you try referencing this variable.

2) What you are seemingly trying to do is not "initialize", but just assign to the static member. You are doing it almost correctly, but you don't need to redeclare the type:

```
void ModulePhysics::Init()
{
    Form::World = /* ... */;
}
```

3) I don't really see why do you need to make anything static to access it from the destructor. Destructor is responsible for deleting instance variables, but they are not yet deleted when the destructor's body is executing. So you may just as well use a "normal" class member, unless you are planning to share its value across different class instances.